# Apache processes are increasing to max everytime even after restart

Tags: apache, drupal

We are facing problem with one of our Drupal sites hosted in apache. Today suddenly, there are 150 httpd2-prefork processes running. This causes site to be down. After every apache restart it comes up for a short while. Then again, number of processes threads grows to max and site goes down. Can anyone else help here?

Comment: probably too many users visiting or spiders crawling?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your server logs and see who your visitors are (real people? bots?), where they're coming from (IP), and what pages they're visiting.

If it's just a few offenders, you can try blocking them. If it's a distributed attack, it's going to be more difficult.

Do you have any modules installed to help block bad people/things? I recommend: [Honeypot](https://drupal.org/project/honeypot) and [Bad Behavior](https://drupal.org/project/badbehavior).